# How can i get the Audio Data With Audio setting in Avfoundation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I added the Microphone device with `AVCaptureSession`. I need audio through the delegateMethod . this method writing the audio on Server every time when I am getting it.
But AUDIO FORMAT is not right. Server required in PCM. So how can I get the audio data in PCM format?
Here is the method that writing data on server:

```
(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{

    AudioBufferList audioBufferList;
    NSMutableData *data=[[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    CMBlockBufferRef blockBuffer;
    CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(sampleBuffer, NULL, &audioBufferList, sizeof(audioBufferList), NULL, NULL, 0, &blockBuffer);

    for( int y=0; y<audioBufferList.mNumberBuffers; y++ )
    {
        AudioBuffer audioBuffer = audioBufferList.mBuffers[y];
        Byte *frame = (Byte*)audioBuffer.mData;
        [data appendBytes:frame length:audioBuffer.mDataByteSize];
    }

    CFRelease(blockBuffer);
    blockBuffer=NULL;

    [outputStream write:[data bytes]maxLength:[data length]];    
}
```

IS THERE ANY WHY TO ADD AUDIO SETTING IN THIS PHASE CODE SO THAT I CAN GET THE DATA ACCORDING TO MY REQUIREMENT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Suggest you review this apple developer document about [AVCaptureAudioDataOutput](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureaudiodataoutput) and here is the sample code about reading and writing using [AVReaderWriter](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/ReaderWriter/).

Comment: link is broken :(